# Can too many connections happen in this php script? (mysql_select_db)

Tags: php, mysql

The script below is used for updating schema of 100 databases.

I am making one call to mysql_connect, does mysql_select_db cause another connection to be made or am I ok? (I run this script to update the schema of 100 or so database)

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "PASSWORD");
$show_db_query = mysql_query('SHOW databases');
$databases = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($show_db_query)) 
{ 
    if (!in_array($row['Database'], $exclude_dbs))
    {
        $databases[] = $row['Database'];
    }
}

foreach($databases as $database)
{
    mysql_select_db($database, $conn);
    echo "Running queries on $database\n***********************************\n";
    foreach($sql_queries as $query)
    {
        if (!empty($query))
        {
            echo "$query;";
            if (!mysql_query($query))
            {
                echo "\n\nERROR: ".mysql_error()."\n\n";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `mysql_select_db` found a last connection or a connection identifer is supplied with the calling statment, it does not create a new connection.

Since you are passing a connection identifer so it does not create a new connection to mysql. you are safe to go in this case of multiple connection but be aware that `mysql` extension is no longer maintained, you could try `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: Thanks! I realize I should be using mysqli, but this is a legacy script and I doubt it won't be removed from php for awhile.